# Pandas: Add data for missing months

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of sales information by customers by month period, that looks something like this, with multiple customers and varying month periods and spend:

```
      customer_id month_year      sales
   0        12    2012-05          2.58   
   1        12    2011-07         33.14  
   2        12    2011-11        182.06   
   3        12    2012-03        155.32   
   4        12    2012-01         71.24
```

As you can see, for each customer many of the months are missing. I would like to add additional rows for each customer, with sales = 0.0, for all of the months in the range of month_year.

Can anyone advise the best way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this; note that the filling the customer_id is not defined (as you probably have this in a groupby or something).

You may need a `reset_index` at the end (if desired)

```
In [130]: df2 = df.set_index('month_year')

In [131]: df2 = df2.sort_index()

In [132]: df2
Out[132]: 
            customer_id   sales
month_year                     
2011-07              12   33.14
2011-11              12  182.06
2012-01              12   71.24
2012-03              12  155.32
2012-05              12    2.58

In [133]: df2.reindex(pd.period_range(df2.index[0],df2.index[-1],freq='M'))
Out[133]: 
         customer_id   sales
2011-07           12   33.14
2011-08          NaN     NaN
2011-09          NaN     NaN
2011-10          NaN     NaN
2011-11           12  182.06
2011-12          NaN     NaN
2012-01           12   71.24
2012-02          NaN     NaN
2012-03           12  155.32
2012-04          NaN     NaN
2012-05           12    2.58

In [135]: df2['customer_id'] = 12

In [136]: df2.fillna(0.0)
Out[136]: 
         customer_id   sales
2011-07           12   33.14
2011-08           12    0.00
2011-09           12    0.00
2011-10           12    0.00
2011-11           12  182.06
2011-12           12    0.00
2012-01           12   71.24
2012-02           12    0.00
2012-03           12  155.32
2012-04           12    0.00
2012-05           12    2.58
```

Comment: This answer assumes that there is only one customer (`customer_id=12`). How about if there are multiple customers and you wish to sort by `customer_id` and `month_year`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a different way to fill in missing months (they will be filled with 0), while also accounting for multiple possible customers.

```
df= (
    df.set_index(["month_year", "customer_id"])[
        "sales"
    ]
    .unstack(fill_value=0)
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
)
```

While this is absolutely unelegant, it gets the job done.