# Pandas-Add missing years in time series data with duplicate years

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, missing-data, reindex

I have a dataset like this where data for some years are missing .

```
County Year Pop
12     1999 1.1
12     2001 1.2
13     1999 1.0
13     2000 1.1
```

I want something like

```
County Year Pop
12     1999 1.1
12     2000 NaN
12     2001 1.2
13     1999 1.0
13     2000 1.1
13     2001 nan
```

I have tried setting index to year and then using reindex with another dataframe of just years method (mentioned here [Pandas: Add data for missing months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343726/pandas-add-data-for-missing-months)) but it gives me error cant reindex with duplicate values. I have also tried df.loc but it has same issue. I even tried a full outer join with blank df of just years but that also didnt work.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make a MultiIndex so you don't have duplicates:

```
df.set_index(['County', 'Year'], inplace=True)
```

Then construct a full MultiIndex with all the combinations:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels)
```

Then reindex:

```
df.reindex(index)
```

The construction of the MultiIndex is untested and may need a little tweaking (e.g. if a year is entirely absent from all counties), but I think you get the idea.

Comment: I'm so using this!

Answer (score 5):

I'm working under the assumption that you may want to add all years between the minimum and maximum years.  It may be the case that you were missing 2000 for both Counties `12` and `13`.

I'll construct a `pd.MultiIndex` `from_product` using `unique` values from the `'County'` column and all integer years between and including the min and max years in the `'Year'` column.

***Note:*** this solution fills in all missing years even if they aren't currently present.

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        df.County.unique(),
        range(df.Year.min(), df.Year.max() + 1)
    ], names=['County', 'Year'])

df.set_index(['County', 'Year']).reindex(mux).reset_index()

   County  Year  Pop
0      12  1999  1.1
1      12  2000  NaN
2      12  2001  1.2
3      13  1999  1.0
4      13  2000  1.1
5      13  2001  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: df.pivot_table(values="Pop", index="County", columns="Year")
Out[11]:
Year    1999  2000  2001
County
12       1.1   NaN   1.2
13       1.0   1.1   NaN
```

and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the result (a Series is required):

```
In [12]: df.pivot_table(values="Pop", index="County", columns="Year").stack(dropna=False)
Out[12]:
County  Year
12      1999    1.1
        2000    NaN
        2001    1.2
13      1999    1.0
        2000    1.1
        2001    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Andy!  I don't think I've answered a question with you before :-)

Comment: @piRSquared surely that's impossible!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try some black magic :P

```
min_year, max_year = df.Year.min(), df.Year.max()

df.groupby('County').apply(lambda g: g.set_index("Year").reindex(range(min_year, max_year+1))).drop("County", axis=1).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you've tried to join to a blank df and this approach can actually  work.

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'County': {0: 12, 1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 13},
 'Pop': {0: 1.1, 1: 1.2, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.1},
 'Year': {0: 1999, 1: 2001, 2: 1999, 3: 2000}})
```

**Solution**

```
#create a new blank df with all the required Years for each County
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.r_[pd.tools.util.cartesian_product([df.County.unique(),np.arange(1999,2002)])].T, columns=['County','Year'])

#Left join the new dataframe to the existing dataframe to populate the Pop values.
pd.merge(df_2,df,on=['Year','County'],how='left')
Out[73]: 
   County  Year  Pop
0      12  1999  1.1
1      12  2000  NaN
2      12  2001  1.2
3      13  1999  1.0
4      13  2000  1.1
5      13  2001  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I didnt include county in my blank df. i see me my mistake now ...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function inspired by the accepted answer but for a case where the time-variable starts and stops at different places for different group ids. The only difference from the accepted answer is that it manually constructs the multi-index.

```
def fill_gaps_in_panel(df, group_col, year_col):
    """
    Fills the gaps in a panel by constructing an index
    based on the group col and the sequence of years between min-year
    and max-year for each group id.
    """
    index_group = []
    index_time = []
    for group in df[group_col].unique():
        _min = df.loc[df[group_col]==group, year_col].min()
        _max = df.loc[df[group_col]==group, year_col].max() + 1
        index_group.extend([group for t in range(_min, _max)])
        index_time.extend([t for t in range(_min, _max)])
    multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
        [index_group, index_time], names=(group_col, year_col))
    df.set_index([group_col, year_col], inplace=True)
    return df.reindex(multi_index)
```