# Update one column based on ring ratio values by month in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For a data frame as the following:

```
   name       date  price  percent
0    wh   2019/1/1    nan     -0.1
1    wh   2019/2/1    nan      0.0
2    wh   2019/3/1    nan      0.0
3    wh   2019/4/1    nan      0.1
4    wh   2019/5/1    nan     -0.1
5    wh   2019/6/1    2.5      0.0
6    sh   2018/6/1    nan      nan
7    sh   2018/7/1    nan     -0.4
8    sh   2018/8/1    nan      0.7
9    sh   2018/9/1    nan     -0.5
10   sh  2018/10/1    nan      0.0
11   sh  2018/11/1    nan      0.4
12   sh  2018/12/1    nan      0.3
13   sh   2019/1/1    nan      nan
14   sh   2019/6/1    2.4      0.0
```

With help from @WeNYoBen:

```
df=df.set_index(['name','date']).unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1 = df.sort_values(['name','date'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   name       date  price  percent
3    sh 2018-06-01    nan      nan
4    sh 2018-07-01    nan     -0.4
5    sh 2018-08-01    nan      0.7
6    sh 2018-09-01    nan     -0.5
0    sh 2018-10-01    nan      0.0
1    sh 2018-11-01    nan      0.4
2    sh 2018-12-01    nan      0.3
7    sh 2019-01-01    nan      nan
8    sh 2019-02-01    nan      nan
9    sh 2019-03-01    nan      nan
10   sh 2019-04-01    nan      nan
11   sh 2019-05-01    nan      nan
12   sh 2019-06-01    2.4      0.0
16   wh 2018-06-01    nan      nan
17   wh 2018-07-01    nan      nan
18   wh 2018-08-01    nan      nan
19   wh 2018-09-01    nan      nan
13   wh 2018-10-01    nan      nan
14   wh 2018-11-01    nan      nan
15   wh 2018-12-01    nan      nan
20   wh 2019-01-01    nan     -0.1
21   wh 2019-02-01    nan      0.0
22   wh 2019-03-01    nan      0.0
23   wh 2019-04-01    nan      0.1
24   wh 2019-05-01    nan     -0.1
25   wh 2019-06-01    2.5      0.0
```

Fill `na` with `zero` for column `percent`:

```
df1['percent'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Last step, if we have all values for `price` column, I can use `df['percent']=df.groupby('name').price.pct_change()` calculating `df['percent']`, but now I need to use `percent` to calculate `price`.

The final result will like this:

```
   name       date  price  percent
0    sh   2018/6/1    2.6      0.0
1    sh   2018/7/1    2.6      0.0
2    sh   2018/8/1    1.6     -0.4
3    sh   2018/9/1    2.6      0.7
4    sh  2018/10/1    1.3     -0.5
5    sh  2018/11/1    1.3      0.0
6    sh  2018/12/1    1.8      0.4
7    sh   2019/1/1    2.4      0.3
8    sh   2019/2/1    2.4      0.0
9    sh   2019/3/1    2.4      0.0
10   sh   2019/4/1    2.4      0.0
11   sh   2019/5/1    2.4      0.0
12   sh   2019/6/1    2.4      0.0
13   wh   2018/6/1    2.8      0.0
14   wh   2018/7/1    2.8      0.0
15   wh   2018/8/1    2.8      0.0
16   wh   2018/9/1    2.8      0.0
17   wh  2018/10/1    2.8      0.0
18   wh  2018/11/1    2.8      0.0
19   wh  2018/12/1    2.8      0.0
20   wh   2019/1/1    2.8      0.0
21   wh   2019/2/1    2.5     -0.1
22   wh   2019/3/1    2.5      0.0
23   wh   2019/4/1    2.5      0.0
24   wh   2019/5/1    2.8      0.1
25   wh   2019/6/1    2.5     -0.1
```

If you have other questions, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

**Related reference:**

[Pandas: Add data for missing months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343726/pandas-add-data-for-missing-months)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `unstack` and `stack` combine

```
df=df.set_index(['name','date']).unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
#df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#df=df.sort_values('date')
df['Pct']=df.groupby('name').price.pct_change()
```

Comment: Thank you. This help me realizing first step, I also have the second step: re-calculating `df[price]` based on `df['percent']` .

Comment: Sorry for unclarity of my question, I think `df['price']` should be updated by reverse deduction method, supposing the price value in `2019/6/1` and `df['percent']` are correct, I want to re-calculate `price` based on it and `df['percent']`.

Comment: Also please check expected result.

Comment: @ahbon one question what is the value *let's say this column's values are correct*

Comment: I means the whole column of `percent`, I need to update and reversely deducte other months' `price` based on whole column of `percent` and the price of `2019/6/1`.

Comment: @ahbon and one more question what is the initial value for wh, where is 2.718763 come from

Comment: Supposing the `price` values except `2019/6/1`, all others are inaccurate, which need to remove and update.

Comment: `2.718763` is fake data, I should use `2.718763` for `wh` and `2.400000` for `bj` and `pct` to calculate other prices.

Comment: @ahbon would you like update your question , I get confused