# Fill gaps in a Period column with 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a Period column.

```
         P   X
0  2021-02   4
1  2021-04  99
2  2021-07  41
3  2021-08  43
```

I want to fill the gaps (the other not shown months between Feb. and Aug. 2021) with `X=0` like this.

```
         P   X
0  2021-02   4
1  2021-03   0
2  2021-04  99
3  2021-05   0
4  2021-06   0
5  2021-07  41
6  2021-08  43
```

Of course I could iterate somehow. But I assume there is a much more elegant pandas solution.

This is the MWE to produce the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'P': [pd.Period(f'2021-0{m}', freq='M') for m in [2, 4, 7, 8]],
    'X': [4, 99, 41, 43],
})

print(df)
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343726/pandas-add-data-for-missing-months) answer will help?

Comment: `df_i = df.set_index(df['P']); df_i.reindex(pd.period_range(df.P.min(),df.P.max()))['X'].fillna(0)` in case you needed a solution